# How to debug why a cascading delete from a foreign key constraint is taking a long time?

Tags: postgresql

The example query is this:

```sql
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)
DELETE FROM user_account
WHERE id IN (10841464,10841563,10841868,10842077,10842163,10842229,10842279,10842326,10842343,10842348,10842354,10842490,10842544,10842923,10843046,10843082,10843119,10843122,10843160,10843189,10843190,10843293,10843306,10843323,10843364,10843517,10843612,10843631,10843710,10843768,10843788,10843837,10843994,10844021,10844031,10844034,10844064,10844111,10844130,10844180,10844191,10844342,10844401,10844426,10844445,10844545,10844569,10844787,10844852,10844879,10844884,10845028,10845747,10845819,10846048,10846139,10846228,10846234,10846236,10846237,10846332,10846337,10846423,10846558,10846639,10846852,10846875,10846971,10847002,10847011,10847031,10847048,10847060,10847146,10847188,10847337,10847959,10847993,10848124,10848139,10848210,10848368,10848424,10848434,10848447,10848450,10848465,10848482,10848494,10848518,10848543,10848598,10848665,10848677,10848740,10848773,10848822,10848858,10848905,10848956);
```

which produces

```
Delete on user_account  (cost=0.43..752.92 rows=0 width=0) (actual time=1.725..1.726 rows=0 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=983 dirtied=2
  ->  Index Scan using user_account_pkey on user_account  (cost=0.43..752.92 rows=100 width=6) (actual time=0.014..0.212 rows=100 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (id = ANY ('{10841464,10841563,10841868,10842077,10842163,10842229,10842279,10842326,10842343,10842348,10842354,10842490,10842544,10842923,10843046,10843082,10843119,10843122,10843160,10843189,10843190,10843293,10843306,10843323,10843364,10843517,10843612,10843631,10843710,10843768,10843788,10843837,10843994,10844021,10844031,10844034,10844064,10844111,10844130,10844180,10844191,10844342,10844401,10844426,10844445,10844545,10844569,10844787,10844852,10844879,10844884,10845028,10845747,10845819,10846048,10846139,10846228,10846234,10846236,10846237,10846332,10846337,10846423,10846558,10846639,10846852,10846875,10846971,10847002,10847011,10847031,10847048,10847060,10847146,10847188,10847337,10847959,10847993,10848124,10848139,10848210,10848368,10848424,10848434,10848447,10848450,10848465,10848482,10848494,10848518,10848543,10848598,10848665,10848677,10848740,10848773,10848822,10848858,10848905,10848956}'::integer[]))
        Buffers: shared hit=385
Planning Time: 0.145 ms
Trigger for constraint user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=15.319 calls=100
Trigger for constraint requested_feature_user_account_id_fk on user_account: time=1.974 calls=100
Trigger for constraint user_account_user_group_history_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=2.972 calls=100
Trigger for constraint user_account_user_group_history_user_actor_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=1.618 calls=100
Trigger for constraint user_account_last_active_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=16.374 calls=100
Trigger for constraint referral_intent_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=134.401 calls=100
Trigger for constraint referral_intent_referral_action_referee_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=8.698 calls=100
Trigger for constraint user_account_stripe_merchant_customer_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=8.033 calls=100
Trigger for constraint independent_portfolio_plan_subscription_user_account_id_fk on user_account: time=7.219 calls=100
Trigger for constraint ledger_account_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=3.410 calls=100
Trigger for constraint user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=4.292 calls=100
Trigger for constraint user_account_list_owner_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=3.164 calls=100
Trigger for constraint user_account_list_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=1.702 calls=100
Trigger for constraint short_url_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=3.319 calls=100
Trigger for constraint instagram_account_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=1.276 calls=100
Trigger for constraint chat_message_recipient_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=4.947 calls=100
Trigger for constraint chat_message_sender_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=3.223 calls=100
Trigger for constraint collaborator_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=1.745 calls=100
Trigger for constraint contra_signup_referral_referred_by_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=1.149 calls=100
Trigger for constraint contra_signup_referral_referred_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=0.904 calls=100
Trigger for constraint contra_transfer_recipient_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=1.343 calls=100
Trigger for constraint contra_transfer_sender_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=1.123 calls=100
Trigger for constraint country_payments_open_notification_request_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=1.097 calls=100
Trigger for constraint crypto_currency_address_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=1.401 calls=100
Trigger for constraint crypto_payout_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=1.334 calls=100
Trigger for constraint email_subscription_settings_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=1.723 calls=100
Trigger for constraint featured_user_account_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=1.085 calls=100
Trigger for constraint globally_suppressed_email_addre_created_by_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=1.042 calls=100
Trigger for constraint hiring_request_match_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=3.585 calls=100
Trigger for constraint job_posting_application_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=1.378 calls=100
Trigger for constraint job_posting_match_email_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=3.325 calls=100
Trigger for constraint job_posting_subcategory_user_account_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=1.264 calls=100
Trigger for constraint job_posting_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=1.940 calls=100
Trigger for constraint job_posting_view_event_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=3.214 calls=100
Trigger for constraint notification_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=1.576 calls=100
Trigger for constraint organization_approved_by_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=4.994 calls=100
Trigger for constraint organization_created_by_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=7.703 calls=100
Trigger for constraint paid_project_cancelled_by_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=1.630 calls=100
Trigger for constraint paid_project_client_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=1.270 calls=100
Trigger for constraint paid_project_contractor_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=1.299 calls=100
Trigger for constraint paid_project_disputed_by_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=1.065 calls=100
Trigger for constraint paid_project_history_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=1.516 calls=100
Trigger for constraint paid_project_inquiry_cc_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=1.331 calls=100
Trigger for constraint paid_project_invite_recipient_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=1.355 calls=100
Trigger for constraint paid_project_invite_sender_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=1.224 calls=100
Trigger for constraint paid_project_terms_declined_user_account_fkey on user_account: time=1.197 calls=100
Trigger for constraint paypal_order_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=0.962 calls=100
Trigger for constraint paypal_payout_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=1.169 calls=100
Trigger for constraint pending_paid_project_inquiry_client_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=1.199 calls=100
Trigger for constraint pending_paid_project_inquiry_contractor_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=3.017 calls=100
Trigger for constraint persona_inquiry_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=1.475 calls=100
Trigger for constraint portfolio_project_blog_author_user_account_fkey on user_account: time=1.387 calls=100
Trigger for constraint portfolio_project_collaborator_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=1.287 calls=100
Trigger for constraint portfolio_project_view_event_viewer_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=1.235 calls=100
Trigger for constraint productized_service_collaborator_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=2.271 calls=100
Trigger for constraint productized_service_sort_order_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=1.426 calls=100
Trigger for constraint productized_service_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=1.919 calls=100
Trigger for constraint productized_service_view_event_viewer_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=1.246 calls=100
Trigger for constraint professional_role_approved_by_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=2.941 calls=100
Trigger for constraint professional_role_created_by_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=2.262 calls=100
Trigger for constraint professional_role_user_account_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=1.339 calls=100
Trigger for constraint professional_tool_approved_by_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=1.216 calls=100
Trigger for constraint professional_tool_created_by_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=1.068 calls=100
Trigger for constraint profile_picture_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=1.605 calls=100
Trigger for constraint project_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=1.917 calls=100
Trigger for constraint requested_feature_user_account_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=1.236 calls=100
Trigger for constraint retool_user_account_flag_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=0.850 calls=100
Trigger for constraint social_media_profile_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=1.335 calls=100
Trigger for constraint stripe_external_account_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=1.322 calls=100
Trigger for constraint stripe_payment_intent_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=1.347 calls=100
Trigger for constraint stripe_payment_method_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=1.344 calls=100
Trigger for constraint stripe_payout_id_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=4.268 calls=100
Trigger for constraint stripe_refund_beneficiary_user_account_id on user_account: time=1.346 calls=100
Trigger for constraint stripe_refund_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=0.940 calls=100
Trigger for constraint stripe_transfer_recipient_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=3.534 calls=100
Trigger for constraint stripe_transfer_sender_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=2.592 calls=100
Trigger for constraint stripe_user_account_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=1.370 calls=100
Trigger for constraint testimonial_author_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=1.164 calls=100
Trigger for constraint testimonial_recipient_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=0.945 calls=100
Trigger for constraint uploaded_file_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=1.209 calls=100
Trigger for constraint uploaded_video_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=1.021 calls=100
Trigger for constraint user_account_authentication_token_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=1.280 calls=100
Trigger for constraint user_account_confirmation_token_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=2.211 calls=100
Trigger for constraint user_account_dismissed_job_posting_user_account_fkey on user_account: time=3.391 calls=100
Trigger for constraint user_account_preferred_professional_tool_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=1.412 calls=100
Trigger for constraint user_account_professional_language_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=1.099 calls=100
Trigger for constraint user_account_user_group_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=2.936 calls=100
Trigger for constraint user_account_work_preferences_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=1.775 calls=100
Trigger for constraint user_payout_method_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=1.512 calls=100
Trigger for constraint user_profile_auto_rating_user_account_fkey on user_account: time=1.407 calls=100
Trigger for constraint user_profile_banner_image_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=1.300 calls=100
Trigger for constraint user_profile_external_link_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=1.665 calls=100
Trigger for constraint user_profile_intro_video_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=1.003 calls=100
Trigger for constraint user_profile_manual_rating_rated_by_fkey on user_account: time=3.285 calls=100
Trigger for constraint user_profile_manual_rating_user_account_fkey on user_account: time=0.934 calls=100
Trigger for constraint user_profile_view_event_subject_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=3.365 calls=100
Trigger for constraint user_profile_view_event_viewer_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=2.850 calls=100
Trigger for constraint user_profile_custom_domain_user_account_id_fkey on user_account: time=6.346 calls=100
Trigger for constraint user_account_list_user_account_list_id_fkey on user_account_list: time=1.387 calls=100
Trigger for constraint short_code_confirmation_attempt_confirmation_token_id_fkey on user_account_confirmation_token: time=1.553 calls=100
Trigger user_account_user_group_after_delete_trigger on user_account_user_group: time=7.157 calls=253
Trigger for constraint user_account_user_profile_avatar_image_id_fkey on user_profile_avatar_image: time=0.915 calls=36
Trigger for constraint job_posting_application_portfolio_project_project_id_fkey on portfolio_project: time=0.855 calls=76
Trigger for constraint notification_portfolio_project_id_fkey on portfolio_project: time=0.702 calls=76
Trigger for constraint organization_portfolio_project_portfolio_project_id_fkey on portfolio_project: time=1.194 calls=76
Trigger for constraint portfolio_project_collaborator_linked_portfolio_project_id_fkey on portfolio_project: time=0.760 calls=76
Trigger for constraint portfolio_project_collaborator_portfolio_project_id_fkey on portfolio_project: time=0.622 calls=76
Trigger for constraint portfolio_project_content_image_portfolio_project_id_fkey on portfolio_project: time=0.747 calls=76
Trigger for constraint portfolio_project_content_video_portfolio_project_id_fkey on portfolio_project: time=0.704 calls=76
Trigger for constraint portfolio_project_external_link_portfolio_project_id_fkey on portfolio_project: time=0.767 calls=76
Trigger for constraint portfolio_project_id_fkey on portfolio_project: time=1.761 calls=76
Trigger for constraint portfolio_project_productized_service_portfolio_project_id_fkey on portfolio_project: time=0.696 calls=76
Trigger for constraint portfolio_project_view_event_portfolio_project_id_fkey on portfolio_project: time=2.131 calls=76
Trigger for constraint professional_role_portfolio_project_portfolio_project_id_fkey on portfolio_project: time=0.786 calls=76
Trigger for constraint professional_tool_portfolio_project_portfolio_project_id_fkey on portfolio_project: time=1.131 calls=76
Trigger for constraint user_profile_auto_rating_project_deductions_project_id_fkey on portfolio_project: time=0.810 calls=76
Trigger for constraint ledger_transaction_entry_account_id_fkey on ledger_account: time=11.073 calls=81
Trigger for constraint stripe_external_account_stripe_user_account_id_fkey on stripe_user_account: time=0.322 calls=10
Trigger for constraint crypto_payout_crypto_currency_address_id_fkey on crypto_currency_address: time=0.838 calls=19
Trigger for constraint user_account_default_crypto_currency_address_id_fkey on crypto_currency_address: time=0.688 calls=19
Trigger for constraint user_payout_method_crypto_currency_address_id_fkey on crypto_currency_address: time=0.414 calls=19
Trigger for constraint notification_productized_service_id_fkey on productized_service: time=0.619 calls=48
Trigger for constraint paid_project_inquiry_productized_service_id_fkey on productized_service: time=0.491 calls=48
Trigger for constraint paid_project_invite_productized_service_id_fkey on productized_service: time=0.468 calls=48
Trigger for constraint pending_paid_project_inquiry_productized_service_id_fkey on productized_service: time=1.427 calls=48
Trigger for constraint portfolio_project_productized_service_productized_service_id_fk on productized_service: time=0.496 calls=48
Trigger for constraint productized_service_collaborator_productized_service_id_fkey on productized_service: time=0.923 calls=48
Trigger for constraint productized_service_deliverable_productized_service_fkey on productized_service: time=0.704 calls=48
Trigger for constraint productized_service_fee_productized_service_id_fkey on productized_service: time=0.884 calls=48
Trigger for constraint productized_service_sort_order_productized_service_id_fkey on productized_service: time=0.611 calls=48
Trigger for constraint productized_service_view_event_productized_service_id_fkey on productized_service: time=1.341 calls=48
Trigger for constraint professional_role_productized_service_productized_service_id_fk on productized_service: time=0.582 calls=48
Trigger for constraint professional_tool_productized_service_productized_service_id_fk on productized_service: time=0.547 calls=48
Trigger for constraint user_profile_auto_rating_service_deductions_service_id_fkey on productized_service: time=0.590 calls=48
Trigger for constraint short_code_confirmation_attempt_authentication_token_id_fkey on user_account_authentication_token: time=0.082 calls=1
Trigger for constraint user_account_authentication_t_user_account_authentication__fkey on user_account_authentication_token: time=0.202 calls=1
Trigger for constraint job_posting_professional_language_job_posting_id_fkey on job_posting: time=0.702 calls=5
Trigger for constraint paid_project_inquiry_job_posting_id_fkey on job_posting: time=0.247 calls=5
Trigger for constraint hiring_request_job_posting_id_fkey on job_posting: time=0.368 calls=5
Trigger for constraint job_posting_application_job_posting_id_fkey on job_posting: time=0.217 calls=5
Trigger for constraint job_posting_deliverable_job_posting_fkey on job_posting: time=0.280 calls=5
Trigger for constraint job_posting_job_posting_subcategory_job_posting_id_fkey on job_posting: time=0.309 calls=5
Trigger for constraint job_posting_match_email_job_posting_id_fkey on job_posting: time=0.284 calls=5
Trigger for constraint job_posting_professional_role_job_posting_id_fkey on job_posting: time=0.293 calls=5
Trigger for constraint job_posting_professional_tool_job_posting_id_fkey on job_posting: time=0.256 calls=5
Trigger for constraint job_posting_view_event_job_posting_id_fkey on job_posting: time=0.147 calls=5
Trigger for constraint notification_job_posting_id_fkey on job_posting: time=0.205 calls=5
Trigger for constraint user_account_dismissed_job_posting_job_posting_fkey on job_posting: time=0.167 calls=5
Trigger for constraint job_posting_application_portfolio_project_application_id_fkey on job_posting_application: time=0.081 calls=1
Trigger for constraint job_posting_application_response_job_posting_application_id_fke on job_posting_application: time=0.159 calls=1
Trigger for constraint paid_project_bonus_paid_project_id_fkey on paid_project: time=1.889 calls=1
Trigger for constraint paid_project_cadence_cylce_paid_project_id_fkey on paid_project: time=0.188 calls=1
Trigger for constraint invoice_paid_project_id_fkey on paid_project: time=0.727 calls=1
Trigger for constraint chat_message_sender_paid_project_id_fkey on paid_project: time=0.088 calls=1
Trigger for constraint job_posting_application_paid_project_id_fkey on paid_project: time=0.057 calls=1
Trigger for constraint paid_project_fee_paid_project_id_fkey on paid_project: time=0.280 calls=1
Trigger for constraint paid_project_history_paid_project_id_fkey on paid_project: time=0.068 calls=1
Trigger for constraint paid_project_inquiry_paid_project_id_fkey on paid_project: time=0.051 calls=1
Trigger for constraint paid_project_invite_paid_project_id_fkey on paid_project: time=0.082 calls=1
Trigger for constraint paid_project_paypal_order_paid_project_id_fkey on paid_project: time=0.128 calls=1
Trigger for constraint paid_project_stripe_payment_intent_paid_project_id_fkey on paid_project: time=0.194 calls=1
Trigger for constraint paid_project_stripe_payout_paid_project_fkey on paid_project: time=0.138 calls=1
Trigger for constraint paid_project_submission_paid_project_id_fkey on paid_project: time=0.171 calls=1
Trigger for constraint paid_project_term_paid_project_id_fkey on paid_project: time=0.163 calls=1
Trigger for constraint paid_project_terms_declined_paid_project_fkey on paid_project: time=0.050 calls=1
Trigger for constraint testimonial_paid_project_id_fkey on paid_project: time=0.049 calls=1
Trigger for constraint hiring_request_match_hiring_request_id_fkey on hiring_request: time=0.288 calls=5
Trigger for constraint paid_project_term_paid_project_fee_id_fkey on paid_project_fee: time=0.069 calls=1
Trigger for constraint paid_project_current_paid_project_term_id_fkey on paid_project_term: time=0.108 calls=1
Trigger for constraint paid_project_term_deliverable_paid_project_fkey on paid_project_term: time=0.210 calls=1
Trigger for constraint paid_project_term_paid_project_milestone_term_id_fkey on paid_project_term: time=0.232 calls=1
Trigger ledger_transaction_entry_after_delete_trigger on ledger_transaction_entry: time=3.395 calls=2
Execution Time: 436.255 ms
```

or this visual reference https://explain.depesz.com/s/bR75#html

[image]

The subject constraint comes from `referral_intent` table.

```sql
postgres=> SELECT conrelid::regclass AS table_from, conname, pg_get_constraintdef(oid)
FROM pg_constraint
WHERE
  contype IN ('f', 'p ') AND
  conname = 'referral_intent_user_account_id_fkey' AND
  connamespace = 'public'::regnamespace
ORDER BY conrelid::regclass::text, contype DESC;
   table_from    |               conname                |                                 pg_get_constraintdef
-----------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 referral_intent | referral_intent_user_account_id_fkey | FOREIGN KEY (referrer_user_account_id) REFERENCES user_account(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
(1 row)
```

The table itself has the necessary indexes and does not have a lot of data:

```sql
postgres=> \d+ referral_intent
                                                                 Table "public.referral_intent"
          Column          |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |           Default            | Storage | Compression | Stats target | Description
--------------------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+------------------------------+---------+-------------+--------------+-------------
 id                       | integer                  |           | not null | generated always as identity | plain   |             |              |
 referrer_user_account_id | integer                  |           | not null |                              | plain   |             |              |
 http_client_id           | integer                  |           | not null |                              | plain   |             |              |
 created_at               | timestamp with time zone |           | not null | now()                        | plain   |             |              |
 updated_at               | timestamp with time zone |           | not null | now()                        | plain   |             |              |
Indexes:
    "referral_intent_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "referral_intent_http_client_id_idx" btree (http_client_id)
    "referral_intent_user_account_id_idx" btree (referrer_user_account_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "referral_intent_http_client_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (http_client_id) REFERENCES http_client(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    "referral_intent_user_account_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (referrer_user_account_id) REFERENCES user_account(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
Referenced by:
    TABLE "referral_intent_referral_action" CONSTRAINT "referral_intent_referral_action_referral_intent_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (referral_intent_id) REFERENCES referral_intent(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
Publications:
    "gce_publication"
Triggers:
    referral_intent_before_update_trigger BEFORE UPDATE ON referral_intent FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION updated_at_before_update_trigger()
Access method: heap
```

Table `referral_intent_referral_action` references `referral_intent` by its PK.

```sql
psql (14.5 (Homebrew), server 14.4)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=> \d referral_intent_referral_action
                              Table "public.referral_intent_referral_action"
         Column          |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |           Default
-------------------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+------------------------------
 id                      | integer                  |           | not null | generated always as identity
 referral_intent_id      | integer                  |           | not null |
 referee_user_account_id | integer                  |           | not null |
 referral_action_id      | integer                  |           | not null |
 created_at              | timestamp with time zone |           | not null | now()
 updated_at              | timestamp with time zone |           | not null | now()
Indexes:
    "referral_intent_referral_action_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "referral_intent_referral_action_referee_user_account_id_idx" btree (referee_user_account_id)
    "referral_intent_referral_action_referral_action_id_idx" btree (referral_action_id)
    "referral_intent_referral_action_referral_intent_id_idx" btree (referral_intent_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "referral_intent_referral_action_referee_user_account_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (referee_user_account_id) REFERENCES user_account(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    "referral_intent_referral_action_referral_action_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (referral_action_id) REFERENCES referral_action(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    "referral_intent_referral_action_referral_intent_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (referral_intent_id) REFERENCES referral_intent(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
Publications:
    "gce_publication"
Triggers:
    referral_intent_referral_action_before_update_trigger BEFORE UPDATE ON referral_intent_referral_action FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION updated_at_before_update_trigger()
```

`referral_intent` table size is tiny (25k rows) and we are deleting just 100 rows in this query.

```sql
postgres=> select schemaname,
relname,
pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(schemaname|| '.' || relname)) as size,
n_live_tup,
n_dead_tup,
CASE WHEN n_live_tup > 0 THEN round((n_dead_tup::float /
n_live_tup::float)::numeric, 4) END AS dead_tup_ratio,
last_autovacuum,
last_autoanalyze
from pg_stat_user_tables
where relname = 'referral_intent'
order by dead_tup_ratio desc NULLS LAST;
 schemaname |     relname     |  size   | n_live_tup | n_dead_tup | dead_tup_ratio |        last_autovacuum        |       last_autoanalyze
------------+-----------------+---------+------------+------------+----------------+-------------------------------+------------------------------
 public     | referral_intent | 1648 kB |      27193 |          0 |         0.0000 | 2022-11-10 11:40:49.533801+00 | 2022-11-10 14:31:14.91536+00
(1 row)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: If you've set `ON CASCADE DELETE` and you have to delete those records across, uh, 170+ tables, it's going to take longer than deleting from one table.

Comment: Of course, but the subject here is a specific table `referral_intent`. Other tables have 10s of millions of records and delete in under a few ms. Whereas this small table is taking more 10x-50x more.

Comment: That particular table has 3 indexes, so you're "deleting" four times - once for the heap and then once for each index.  It's taking less than half a second to execute a delete across 170+ tables - I question the need to focus on less than 10% of that execution time.

Comment: You are not deleting only 100 rows though. You are deleting 100 rows from the user_account table and all referencing rows from other tables. They may well be 10k rows in that referral_intent table that are referencing those 100.

Comment: Can you add the `\d referral_intent_referral_action` output as well? Also what version of Postgres and whether there have been migrations from older versions.

Comment: Maybe just the index is bloated though the table is not?  Anyway, a way to get a more or less definitive answer is to enable auto_explain with auto_explain.log_nested_statements, auto_explain.log_analyze and auto_explain.log_buffers all set to ON, and with auto_explain.log_min_duration set to some small value, maybe even zero.  If you are a superuser, you can make the changes only in the local session to avoid flooding the log files.